# c++ two objects with const pointers to each other

Tags: c++

I have two objects, A and B, which are both derived from a common base class, and both contained within a separate parent class. I want A and B to have access to pointers or references to each other, so that they can call each others' member functions. Ideally, those pointers / references would be const, so that they can't be changed. But if this is the case then they must be initialized. I am having trouble finding a solution to this problem because clearly one or the other, A or B, must be initialized before the other.

Stripped down, this is what I want to achieve:

```
class Base
{
};

class A : public Base
{
 public:
   Base& const refToB;
   //some constructor here, but how can it refer to an object that doesn't yet exist?
};

class B : public Base
{
 public:
   Base& const refToA;
   // some constructor here
};

class Parent
{
 public:
 A a;
 B b;
};
```

Clearly there is circular logic here, but I feel like it's reasonable to ask for two objects which can reference each other, without having to compromise on the const. Is there a way out?

There are a few more details about my situation. I fear that they would obscure the main question, so I will post in the comments below.

Comment: IIRC references can't be `const`, but they can't be changed after binding so they don't need to be `const`.

Comment: This seems like a terrible design decision. It's far too tightly coupled and will easily become a maintenance nightmare. You should consider alternative solutions.

Comment: Here are some more details, though I think that none of them change the essence of the question.

1. I said that the classes A and B need to have access to pointers / references to each other, but this does not mean they need to contain them as member variables. They could, for instance, contain a reference to a common object (probably Parent) which itself contains the references to A and B. However, I haven't been able to break the circular dependency with this solution.

Comment: 2. In fact, I want to have more than 2 classes with references to each other--probably 5 or 6 in total. I intent to reduce the overhead here by having A B C... inherit from another class which takes care of the references. But again, I don't think that this changes the circular dependency.

Comment: I think you are just going to have to use pointers here. References need to be bound upon *initialization* and you can't initialize multiple objects simultaneously. But there may be a better way to structure what you need. Are you building a network? What are you trying to do with this?

Comment: @RetiredNinja Can you suggest some alternative design solutions? I'm fairly new to programming and am having trouble thinking laterally about it. The general situation seems to me to be quite generic: I have multiple GUI components and I want them to be able to call each other (ie. press a button here and have it call another element. What is the best solution for this, if not through references / pointers?

Comment: @Galik, I have no problem using pointers instead of references. Please see my previous comment for a few more details of what I'm trying to build.

Answer (score 3):

> I am having trouble finding a solution to this problem because clearly one or the other, A or B, must be initialized before the other.

You can use:

```
class Base
{
};

class A;
class B;

class A : public Base
{
   public:
      A(B const& b) : refToB(b) {}
      B const& refToB;
};

class B : public Base
{
   public:
      B(A const& a) : refToA(a) {}
      A const& refToA;
};

class Parent
{
   public:
      A a;
      B b;

      Parent() : a(b), b(a) {}
};
```

However, this is the only way you can initialize objects of type `A` and `B`. You wouldn't be able to initialize them without a container object.

It's not clear why you want to design your classes that way. There is very likely a better design that will serve your needs.

Comment: Does this emit warnings about b being used uninitialized?

Comment: @R Sahu, thanks for your answer. Can you help me think about better design approaches? The problem that I am trying to solve is how to let one component communicate with another. Let's say that I have one GUI component which is a button; I want it to be able to access member functions of another component, let's say a database. I don't want the button to be a member of the database, because I am trying to keep the GUI and core components separate in my code (so that the core could be ported to another system in the future). The only solution I can see is giving a pointer / ref to the button.

Comment: The example I have just given doesn't explain why both components need to refer to each other. But the system I'm building is more complicated, with multiple GUI elements which will need to interact with each other in different ways. My plan was to give them all access to each other through the Base class, thereby minimizing repetitive code and allowing for easier maintenance (i.e. so that I don't need to worry about creating new access routes every time I write a new function).
What are the problems with this approach, and what would you recommend as a better approach?

Comment: @Eric, I don't see any warning with `-Wall` under `g++`. It's ok because the code only initializes a reference, doesn't get or set the value.

Comment: @LiamGoodacre, there are several GUI architectures that address that requirement. I am familiar with the event/callback mechanism used by X/Xt and the signal/slot mechanism used by Qt. If you search for "GUI paradigm" and "GUI architecture" on the net, you are likely to find something that makes sense to you.

Comment: @R Sahu, the [http://simmesimme.github.io/tutorials/2015/09/20/signal-slot](Signal Slot paradigm) looks brilliant and would definitely work in this situation. 
Would you mind looking at the answer I gave below (of simply making a and b public inside parent) and telling me what you think? From what I can see, this is an extremely simple way of solving the problem, and hence might be favorable here. However, I don't want to create headaches for myself in the future, and someone with your experience might be able to see problems with this approach which I can't.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question, here is the best solution I've come up with so far. Classes A and B (which represent GUI elements) inherit from a class Base, which contains a static pointer to the *parent* object. The same parent object grants friend access to A and B, so that they can access each other's public functions as needed. The advantage of this system is that you can create and link in new GUI objects (C, D...) very easily: all you need to do is inherit from Base and update the friendship in Parent.

Here is the code:

```
class Parent; // forward declaration for Base class static variable

class Base       // class Base is just there to hold a pointer to the parent object for its derived classes
{
private:
    static Parent * parent_ptr;
public:
    Parent* getParent() const { return parent_ptr; }
};

class A : public Base
{
public:
    int a_int;
    A(const int a) : a_int(a) {}
    void someFunction() const { std::cout << a_int; }
};

class B : public Base
{
public:
    int b_int;
    B(const int b) : b_int(b) { doSomethingToA(); }  // Initiating this from the constructor, but really I would want to wait for a Listener
    void doSomethingToA() const;
};

class Parent
{
private:
    A a = { 2 };
    B b = { 3 };
    friend class A;
    friend class B;
} parent;

Parent* Base::parent_ptr = &parent;

void B::doSomethingToA() const  { getParent()->a.someFunction(); }
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code that reflects your thought. It's not fully clear to me how the updated code will look like.

Comment: @R Sahu I have expanded on the original idea and edited my answer with example code. What do you think?